# Error34, 'Result too large'

Tags: python

So i wanted to do a gradient descent in Python so that i can find the global minimum of f, where x=10, learning rate is 0.01, epsilon is 0.00001 and max. number of iterations is 10000

```py
# parameters to set
x = 10 # Starting value of x
alpha = 0.01 # Set learning rate
epsilon = 0.00001 # Stop algorithm when absolute difference between 2 consecutive x-values is less than epsilon
max_iter = 10000 # set maximum number of iterations

# Define function and derivative of function
f = lambda x: x**4-3*x**3+15
fprime = lambda x: 4*x**3-9*x**2

# Initialising
diff = 1 # initialise difference between 2 consecutive x-values
iter = 1 # iterations counter

# Now Gradient Descent
while diff > epsilon and iter < max_iter: # 2 stopiing criteria
    x_new = x - alpha * fprime(x) # update rule
    print("Iteration ", iter, ": x-value is:", x_new,", f(x) is: ", f(x_new) )
    diff = abs(x_new - x)
    iter = iter + 1
    x = x_new
    
print("The local minimum occurs at: ", x)
```

But the thing is, when i run the entire code, it only manages to print out 5 iterations and then i encounter a OverFlowError message.

[image: --]

Comment: what's the value of x_new?

Comment: x_new = x - alpha * fprime(x)

Comment: @ewong `x_new` =  6.458476928893455e+153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your learning rate is too high, and thus causing the divergence that you're observing. A value of `alpha = 0.001` converges to a local minimum:

```
# parameters to set
x = 10 # Starting value of x
alpha = 0.001 # Set learning rate
epsilon = 0.00001 # Stop algorithm when absolute difference between 2 consecutive x-values is less than epsilon
max_iter = 10000 # set maximum number of iterations

# Define function and derivative of function
f = lambda x: x**4-3*x**3+15
fprime = lambda x: 4*x**3-9*x**2

# Initialising
diff = 1 # initialise difference between 2 consecutive x-values
iter = 1 # iterations counter

# Now Gradient Descent
while diff > epsilon and iter < max_iter: # 2 stopiing criteria
    x_new = x - alpha * fprime(x) # update rule
    print("Iteration ", iter, ": x-value is:", x_new,", f(x) is: ", f(x_new) )
    diff = abs(x_new - x)
    iter = iter + 1
    x = x_new
    
print("The local minimum occurs at: ", x)
```